# QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults - Email Templates Render Without Respecting Non Writable Sections

Tags: apex, email-template, quickaction

We are loading default email templates into the service console using QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults.

This is working however a user can insert text into the any section of the email template which is not correct. If the user manually selects a template they can only write into the designated section on the custom HTML template which is correct.

Does anyone know if it's possible to load default email templates automatically which respect read-only/writable areas?

This is specified in the HTML template using "div contentEditable = true".

Thanks

Comment: Which type of email template is this? Can you share the default email template apex class?

Comment: Thanks for the message. Unfortunately contentEditable is not supported by Salesforce. SF are now removing support for manually selected templates too so we will have to find another HTML tag/approach. This is actually quite a big problem for us becasue we will have to recreate many many templates using VF instead. If I do find an answer I'll be sure to post it up though

Comment: As a side note, in Lightning you can add a Default Email template as part of a customized Email action.